# Hooks/controls on a bendy bone?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I have some hair being controlled by a bendy bone, set up following this tutorial (head bone > bendy bone > tail bone): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsJ3Grq_3GM

This rigging method is convenient for hair as I can do all the manipulations by moving/rotating the tail bone, and it doesn't have issues with pole angles/bending angles like IK. But I want to get a bit more control. I would like to be able to grab individual segments and move them around, like adding more points on a curve, or do some other effect that is similar. Is there any way to do this, or a similar rigging setup that would allow for it?

Comment: if you need more control points than a simple bezier segment has, you need to look into Spline IK and setup it like this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/35442/7777 or this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27655/7777